# Eclipse Error: "Error has occured, see the log file..."

Tags: eclipse

So, this is a problem I've been having with Eclipse recently.

I downloaded it a few weeks ago, and launched it successfully the first time, but now it won't load. When I try to open Eclipse it gives me the message

"Error has occurred, see the log file YOUR_WORKSPACE/.metadata/.plugins/.log."

I've done quite a bit of research but all I can find doesn't work. I've tried deleting YOUR_WORKSPACE/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.core.resources/, however, there isn't even a .snap folder in here. I've tried re-downloading the JDE and JDK as well as Eclipse itself. However, I'm also on a Mac, so a lot of the solutions don't apply to me.

I have checked the log file, like suggested, but I'm quite new to this, so it's all gibberish to me and in code.

I can't seem to send the log file, as it's too long and it's in the wrong format so I can't post it.

Please help if you can!

Comment: At least share the error in your log file.

Comment: Sorry, the log file is too long for me to share.

Comment: Not the whole thing. Try to identify where the error is logged. There's probably a stack trace near the end.

Comment: Could this be it?

Comment: !ENTRY org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench 4 0 2017-10-18 20:21:54.750
!MESSAGE FrameworkEvent ERROR
!STACK 0
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/annotation/PreDestroy
 at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.disposed(InjectorImpl.java:450)
 at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.Requestor.disposed(Requestor.java:156)
 at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.contexts.ContextObjectSupplier$ContextInjectionListener.update(ContextObjectSupplier.java:78)
 at

Comment: org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.contexts.TrackableComputationExt.update(TrackableComputationExt.java:111)
 at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.contexts.TrackableComputationExt.handleInvalid(TrackableComputationExt.java:74)
 at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.contexts.EclipseContext.dispose(EclipseContext.java:178)
 at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.contexts.osgi.EclipseContextOSGi.dispose(EclipseContextOSGi.java:99)
 at

Comment: Please use the "edit" link under your question to add details to your question - the comments are not meant for that.

Comment: You are trying to use Eclipse with Java 9. You need to use Eclipse Oxygen.1a (4.7.1a) released a few days ago for that.

Comment: Thanks! It seems to be working now.